# Windows music player that supports play folder via context menu

Tags: windows, music, media-player

Please recommend a Windows music player that supports play folder via the context menu similar to VLC (see picture).

And please don't recommend player where the user needs to make the context menu option. It has to be built into the installer of the program.
Also, it must support adding a folder (not selecting a group of music files).

[image: VLC Context Menu UI]

Answer (score 1):

I believe GOM Player has that feature. Give it a try: https://gomlab.com/

Just curious, why not just using VLC?

Answer (score 0):

[Snaeplayer](https://snaeplayer.com) is a simple, browser-based music player (as a Progressive Web App, thus installable).

It has it's own library, where you can [import whole directories](https://snaeplayer.com/library/tracks) from the file system.

It's working on all modern browsers on all major platforms, including Windows.