# What is a simple folder music player for Windows?

Tags: windows, music, media-player

I am looking for a free and simple music player for windows that has the following features:

- It is either GUI or command line interface
- I can select a folder with music files that the player is playing
- It should play the files in order or randomly
- I do not care about Album or Artist information at all.

There is "Windows Media Player" but this app has many features I am not interested in (Burn, Sync, Playlists, too much confusion on the GUI, there is no "Open" menu, i.e. there is no menu at all)...

I already tried:

- Windows Media Player
- Folder Player: UI seems to be broken, no shuffle
- mplayer: unable to install

On my other computer (Mac) I always used `mplayer` which worked perfectly.

Comment: You could tell us which ones you have tried already.

Comment: This answer https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/88551/12170 for a similar question might fit your requirements, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/downloads.html). You can play folders or even set up playlists.

It is open source, and runs on Windows, Linux, MacOS. I have used it on Windows for a few years now.

It is typically updated say once a year or more, but development is ongoing via [github](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet).

Comment: Just tried this but it is not very intuitive and I cannot see how I can select the files of a folder...

Comment: Go to Menu: File/Add Folder.

Comment: You can also add a folder permanently by going to: File/Preferences/Library. Then you can add a directory to "Scan Directories". GUI is not great but works and has a powerful search too.

Answer (score 0):

[Winamp](https://www.winamp.com/downloads/) is a Windows application aimed at playing music and other audio files. The program's powerful media library allows you to navigate through large databases at lightning speed, create playlists and, of course, listen to music. Winamp is developed exclusively for Microsoft Windows and is officially compatible with Windows 8 and Windows 10, but older versions of Windows can still run the current Winamp version.

Comment: The link unfortunately does not work and on the store it is not free

Comment: @Alex Yesterday it worked. Try it later again, the program is defenetly free.

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe it is just temporarily down...

Comment: @Alex Yo can try alternative link https://winamp-full.en.uptodown.com/windows/download

Comment: @Alex Original link is working again.

Answer (score 0):

There are many simple players, but [AIMP](https://www.aimp.ru/) would be my recommendation. You can use "classic" interface to have a very simple UI, then you can just click "+" to add a folder or drag & drop into it. It also has lot of options and extensibility (plugins, themes) to suit it for your needs.